# How to remove blanks from select options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, activerecord, model-view-controller

What's a best practice to remove blanks `select` options?

[image]

**form**

```
<%= f.select :challenge_id, options_for_select(@current_user_challenges.collect { |current| [current.full_challenge, current.id] }) %>
```

**challenges_controller**

```
#My Attempts:
@current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at).where("user_id > 0")
@current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at).reject!(&:blank?)
@current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at).reject { |id| id.blank? }
@current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at).select!{|val| !val.empty?}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select values with `present?` check

```
@current_user_challenges = 
  current_user.includes(:challenges).challenges.order(:created_at).select{ |challenge| challenge.full_challenge.present? }
```

Also, I will suggest you can add a `presence validation` at model level

```
class Challenge
  validates :full_challenge, presence: true
end
```

Comment: `includes` help you reduce the `N+1` queries